# Hardware (PC parts) slotting website

Tags: processor, motherboard, pc, power-supply, ethernet

I am in a need of any kind of simulation website/software that can allow a person to slot in the right parts in a PC.
For example, if you put in RAM where a graphics card should be, there would be an error or you would lose points.

Do you know of any such website/resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably wanting something like [PC Building Simulator](https://www.pcbuildingsim.com/).  It isn't free and it isn't a website, but it sounds like the program you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is a game as you said and I just need a basic simulation. I already found this, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate you trying to help though. Thanks a lot